NTFS - how to create a list of corrupted files(suspecting a MFT corruption on SSD)
Sudden BSOD, computer did not want to boot anymore, System Repair could not repair it.
SSD has no SMART errors, checked it with a Linux LiveCD.
I cloned it and allowed chkdsk to attempt to fix the errors. There were a lot of files where it said "Windows replaced bad clusters in file".
I'm suspecting a MFT corruption, parts of various files being read from incorrect pointers.
I'm interested to find a way to create a list of these files that chkdsk finds as being corrupted. The problem is that they are many and chkdsk does not show their full path completely, it a short like this: "c:\progra~1\" instead of "c:\program files\"
Any other tools that I could run on a fresh clone that would allow me to identify the corrupted files?
Is there anything I could do to investigate more this possible MFT corruption?

one question was enough, why making two of them?

because they are different questions.
